# Copying files from home directory to computer directory

Tags: cp, mv

I am trying to copy a .php file from my Documents directory to `/var/www/html`.
I would do this in the GUI, but I don't have root access, only in the terminal. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run your file manager with root privileges. *Please be careful, though. There's nothing stopping you from killing your installation if you do this.*

The recommended method is to use `gksudo`. If you have Unity or GNOME, the command is:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

You'll get the file manager with root privileges. If you don't have Nautilus, you can try `caja` or `dolphin`.

If you don't want to install `gksudo`, you can also do:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

This uses root's configuration to open Nautilus, which prevents potential permission errors when saving configs.